# Initializing a collection auto-property inline: behaviour seems different between C# and VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

Context: I am converting a program from C# to VB.  The program runs with Entity Framework (latest, but not EFCore).

In a C# class,  I have an auto-property for a collection, initialised thus:

```
public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;} = new List<Student>();
```

This runs fine with EF.

Converted to VB this becomes:

```
Public Overridable Property Students As ICollection(Of Student) = New List(Of Student)()
```

Strangely, the latter seems not work with Entity Framework, yielding a *run-time* error stating

*The property 'Students' ... cannot be set because the collection is already set to an EntityCollection.*

I can fix this error by reverting to the older long-winded way to initialise a collection (which I used to have to do in C# also before it had initialization of auto-properties):

```
Private _students As ICollection(Of Student) = New List(Of Student)

Public Overridable Property Students As ICollection(Of Student)
  Get
    Return _students
  End Get
  Set(value as ICollection(Of Student))
    _students = value
  End Set
End Property
```

I had thought that the above long-winded code and the single line that replaced it were functionally equivalent.  Can anyone explain to me why they are different AND why/how this is different to the C# equivalent (where the long-winded and one-line equivalents appear to have the same behaviour).

Comment: If it is entity, the classes get initialized when the app is started so "NEW" is not necessary.

Comment: This is something that might require digging into the IL to see how they were translated differently.

Comment: @jdweng: Could you elaborate? I'm not in the EF world, but not requiring 'new' in VB only seems rather strange.

Comment: You have classes that need to be initialize with data from a database (the datasource).  So the constructor (new) has to be called once.  The classes also have a datasource.  It appears the error message indicates the datasource  was already set in a class when you tried to add a new datasource.

Comment: @jdweng: And the long-winded property works because ...?

Comment: Normally with c# I would use : public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}  (without  the end of line = new List<Student>())  Not sure how c# handles the new along with the get/set.  It looks like c# is ignoring the "new" while vb.net isn't ignoring the "new".

Comment: @jdweng. I do need to initialize the collection with the new List. This is so that in I can set up associations between objects in the Data Initializer, and also, when running, to create and persist object graphs in one go.  I have been building large systems this way for many years.  It works fine in C#, and, as explaimed, it works in VB using the long-winded code, but it does not work - in VB only - for an auto-property initialized inline.

Comment: In normal operation, the new List is called when the object is instantiated, but EF then replaces it with the EntityCollection crafted from the associations in the database. Notice that the error message suggests that the property already contains an EntityCollection, not a List -  even more surprising.

Comment: What is the difference between a Collection and a List?  As I said this looks like a DataSource issue and probably not an initialization issue.

Comment: @jdweng. There is no Collection. ICollection is an interface implemented by all concrete collections in .NET including List and EntityCollection. Trust me this is not the issue. The issue is to do, somehow, with VB's different implementation of an initialized auto-property -  because there is no issue with the long-winded version.

Comment: I agree that it is internal to the c#/vb.net compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Some further investigation does not fully answer my question, but does at least confirm that there is a difference between how the C# and VB versions of the initialized collection auto-property work.

In the C# version, if I add a zero param constructor (empty implementation) and put a breakpoint on it, then when retrieving an object (via EF), by the time the constructor is hit, the auto-property *has already been initialized* with a new List. (This then gets replaced, presumably after the constructor exits, with the EntityCollection from EF).

In the VB version,  if I add a zero param constructor (empty implementation) and put a breakpoint on it, then when retrieving an object from EF, by the time the constructor is hit, the auto-property *is still Nothing (null)*.

So I'm guessing that in VB, immediately the constructor exits, EF gets in and puts its EntityCollection in the property *before* the property initializer is then called. This scenario would be consistent both with the breakpoint observation and the error message.

I find it very surprising that C# and VB should differ on something as basic as the construction sequence.

(N.B. It probably doesn't make a difference in many circumstances, but I'm guessing it makes a difference in EF because the latter is doing dynamic proxying.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of the problem is that VB initializes fields *after* calling the base class constructor while C# initializes fields *before* calling the base class constructor.
[https://anthonydgreen.net/2019/02/12/exhausting-list-of-differences-between-vb-net-c/#:~:text=16.-,VB%20initializes%20fields%20AFTER%20the%20base%20constructor%20call%20whereas%20C%23,BEFORE%20the%20base%20constructor%20call](https://anthonydgreen.net/2019/02/12/exhausting-list-of-differences-between-vb-net-c/#:%7E:text=16.-,VB%20initializes%20fields%20AFTER%20the%20base%20constructor%20call%20whereas%20C%23,BEFORE%20the%20base%20constructor%20call)

This is a hard problem to account for when converting code - you just have to be aware of it. It's especially difficult converting from C# to VB, because as far as I can see, there's no way to force field initialization before the base class constructor call since if "MyBase.New" exists, then it must be the first statement in the body of a constructor in VB.

Comment: That's a useful link, thanks, Dave - and a rather longer list of differences than I had imagined!